# Missing on off button font/icon/glyph in gnome-control-center after upgrading from stretch to buster

Tags: debian, gnome3, fonts, icons

I recently upgraded a Debian Stretch installation to Buster using [the official guide](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting). I just noticed I'm missing some font/icon/glyph on the on/off switches in gnome-control-center. Where the icons should be it shows 23F0 for on and 2858 for off. I tried a couple things, but nothing solved my issue.

- reinstall gnome-control-center
  `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`
- rebuild the font cache
  `sudo fc-cache -f -v`
- Changed the fonts in gnome-tweak.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot gnome-control-center]

Answer (score -1):

Run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, today some of the updated packages fixed this issue.